# Generate Solr cores from an existing one

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

I have a Solr core with hundreds of millions of documents.
I want to create 100 duplicates of this core where I only change 2-3 fields (time and ID) on the original docs and save them to the new cores (so each core contains a different time data for testing).
I need it to work as fast as possible.
I was thinking opening the core files with Lucene and read the entire content while writing the altered documents to a new index but I've realized I'll need to configure all the analyzers of the destination core which may be complex and in additional not all my fields are stored.
If there is a low level API in Lucene to alter documents / indexes, I could copy the index files and change the documents on the lowest level.
Anyone familiar with such?

Comment: I think [this](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#SolrEntityProcessor) fits your use case exactly.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of it but it doesn't fit my needs because not all my fields are stored.